# I am not able to use the mail command in my unix system .. it just says EOT at the end and terminates

Tags: unix, scripting

I am a newbie in Unix shell scripting, I am not able to properly send mails using the mail command in the Unix. Here is the thing that's happening.

> shans-MacBook-Air:shansdir shanraja$ mail -s "test" shanraja1911@gmail.com
>   this is my first mail.
>
> EOT

Comment: What are you typing to end it? What have you tried? Are you following an example like [this](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-mail-command-examples/)?

Comment: Also, based on your hostname it seems that you're on MacOS, which is _very important information_ that you left out. What version of operating system are you using? Are you using the Terminal app?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this with the option -q to start the message so the following

```
mail -s "test" email -q "this is my first mail."
```